# Error: A crypto suite has not been assigned to this client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have downloaded ***hyperledger-fabric v2.0*** fabric-samples repository, started the network, followed through the fabtoken example, everything seems to be working as it should.

Problems started when I tried to modify the fabtoken example in order to support creating additional users for the default organization. I am trying to register new users to the organization on the network by following [How to use a common connection profile](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html) tutorial for the Node SDK. However, *initCredentialStores()* method doesn't seem to initialize *crypto_suite* field of the *Client.js* file, because of which I get the ***Error: A crypto suite has not been assigned to this client*** error when I try to call the *client.getCertificateAuthority()* method.

I have tried to debug through the initialization of the Credential Stores (*initCredentialStores()* method). The problem seems to occur when *const crypto_suite = BaseClient.newCryptoSuite();* is called, but I couldn't determine the root cause of the error.

RegiserNewUser function:

```
async function registerNewUser(client, caService, admin, uname){
    await client.setUserContext(admin, true);

    client.loadFromConfig('/home/todorovic/fabric-samples/basic-network/connection.yaml');
    client.loadFromConfig('/home/todorovic/fabric-samples/basic-network/org1.yaml')
    client.initCredentialStores().then(_ => {console.log('zavrsio init');});

    const ca_client = client.getCertificateAuthority();
    ca_client.register({enrollmentID: uname, affiliation: 'Org1'}, admin)
    .then((secret) => 
        {return client.setUserContext({username: uname, password: secret});
    });

}
```

The connection.yaml remains unchanged, while the Org1.yaml file that I added looks like this:

```
name: "Org1 Client"
version: "1.0"

client:
  organization: Org1
  credentialStore:
    path: "/tmp/hfc-cvs/org1"
    cryptoStore:
      path: "/tmp/hfc-cvs/org1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line in your example

```
client.initCredentialStores().then(_ => {console.log('zavrsio init');});
```

to

```
await client.initCredentialStores();
```

otherwise the credential stores will not have been initialised before your code tries to get the certificate authority.